# How to silently copy large number of files using 'cp' command?

Tags: bash, cp

`cp` by default displays the list of all the files being copied.  I'm using the command:

```
sudo cp -r $WORKSPACE/DMS/dist/conf/* $WORKSPACE/DMS/NewWar/NewFiles/conf
```

and this displays the complete and long list of files being copied as below:

```
+ sudo cp -r /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/XmlSchema-1.3.1.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/XmlSchema-LICENSE.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/activation-LICENSE.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/annogen-0.1.0.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/annogen-LICENSE.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/antlr.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axiom-api-1.2.4.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axiom-api-LICENSE.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axiom-dom-1.2.4.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axiom-dom-LICENSE.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axiom-impl-1.2.4.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axiom-impl-LICENSE.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axis.jar /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/axis2-LICENSE.txt /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/6.5.10/DMS/OldBase/dist/sharedlib/backport-util-concurrent-2.2.jar
```

... and the list goes on.  How to silently copy the files in this case?

Comment: It looks like you have enabled shell debugging (`set -x`). What is the output of `echo $-`?

Comment: @steeldriver: Yes, I've used `set -x`. I had to in order to echo the other commands of the script which are necessary for the logs. Any was in which we can silent out the `cp`?

Comment: When I put `echo $-` in my script it simply gives the output as: `+ echo x  
x`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you must use `set -x` for the rest of your script but don't want to see it for the `cp` command just turn it off before you `cp` and then back on afterwards.

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
...
set +x
sudo cp -r "$WORKSPACE/DMS/dist/conf/"* "$WORKSPACE/DMS/NewWar/NewFiles/conf"
set -x
...
```

Note you shouldn't use `sudo` in a script and you should quote all variables.

Comment: Why should you not use sudo in a script?

Comment: @DarkHeart: Use least permissions where possible and users running the script may not have sudo access.  Chances are the file permissions could just be changed on the associated directories so there would be no need for root access to perform a simple copy